# touchesbegan for dismissing keyboard textview under scrollview not working

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, uitextfield

I have a text field under a view which is under a scroll view inside a  view controller which is one of the view controllers  of  a navigation controller.   I want to dismiss the keyboard when the user touches outside the textfield.  I tried using `touchesBegan:`, but it is not firing when it's under the  scrollview.   I also tried disabling user interaction in the scroll view, but nothing worked. Could anyone help me out?

```
 func dismissKeyboard(txtField:UITextField)
    {
        txtField.resignFirstResponder()

    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        dismissKeyboard(firstNameTxt)
     }
```

Changed the below way for it to work

```
extension AddEditHireViewController {
    func hideKeyboard()
    {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: "dismissKeyboardNew")

        self.formView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    }

    func dismissKeyboardNew()
    {
         self.formView.endEditing(true)
        // self.dismissKeyboard(self.firstNameTxt)

    } }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst the solution given by Matthew Bradshaw works too, it will not dismiss the keyboard if the user scrolls. If you want it to do that, another solution would be to subclass `UIScrollView`. You could then override the `touchesBegan` method in this subclass, and then end editing accordingly.

```
class DismissableScrollView: UIScrollView {
    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        endEditing(false)
    }
}
```

Once you have done this, simply change your existing `UIScrollView`'s class to `DismissableScrollView`, or if you are already subclassing `UIScrollView`, you could add this to that subclass.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info Could you please explain me more on this one "it will not dismiss the keyboard if the user scrolls."  Was testing it but not able to get the scenario your talking about

Comment: @Arav as far as I'm aware, `UITapGestureRecogniser`s get cancelled when the user pans. This may not be the case however.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.   Tested with the dismissablescrollview.  When I pan it's not dismissing the keyboard.  Do I need to override some other method?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to create an extension of the view controller.  This has worked much smoother for me and with less hassle than trying to use `.resignFirstResponder()`

```
extension UIViewController
{
    func hideKeyboard()
    {
        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(
            target: self,
            action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))

        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    func dismissKeyboard()
    {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Call `self.hideKeyboard()` in the `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Thanks a lot Mathew it works.  But my app was crushing when I tried to use your action selector  so i need to change the selector part to make it  work Pasted the changes in question section

Comment: Pasted the change  i did in question section .  If i use this way selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard) it's not working.  Not sure why is it so

Comment: @Arav just a heads up, using strings as selectors is deprecated in Swift 2, and the feature will be removed entirely in Swift 3.

Comment: @Arav I'm not sure why it was crashing.  What was the error message?

Comment: It was crashing at the class AppDelegate.  Error messages was able to not finding the selector

Comment: "using strings as selectors is deprecated in Swift 2,"   could you post some good links of using selector I am unable to find it in swift doco